# How to prove this function is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a function $f:\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $f:(x_1,x_2) \mapsto x_1^2+x_2^2 $. And the metric $d:((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) \mapsto |x_1-y_1|+2|x_2-y_2|$. How can I prove such a function is continuous?

I understand what to do in principle but I am struggling to manipulate the inequalities to get what I want:

Here is what I have so far:

Consider $$|f((x_1,x_2))-f((a_1,a_2))|=|(x_1^2+x_2^2)-(a_1^2+a_2^2)|=|(x_1^2-a_1^2)+(x_2^2-a_2^2)| \leq |(x_1^2-a_1^2)|+|(x_2^2-a_2^2)| = |(x_1-a_1)||(x_1+a_1)|+|(x_2-a_2)||(x_2+a_2)| \leq |(x_1-a_1)||(x_1+a_1)|+2|(x_2-a_2)||(x_2+a_2)|$$

Now this is looking almost like $|x_1-a_1|+2|x_2-a_2|$ which is what I need to get in order to help me see a nice choice for $\delta$ that will work for all $\epsilon > 0$.

I suspect we need to say something like $\delta=\text{min}\{...\}$ but I can't quite see how to kill this off.

Any help?

Comment: consider $f$ as a sum of two functions.

Comment: When you're considering continuity at $(a_1,a_2)$, these are fixed. Then you can assume $|x_1-a_1| < 1$, $|x_2-a_2| < 1$ so that $|x_1| < 1+|a_1|$ and $|x_2| < 1+|a_2|$. Then $|x_1+a_1| \le 1+2|a_1|$ and $|x_2+a_2| \le 1+2|a_2$. Then you can found the difference in function values by a constant involving $a_1,a_2$ times $(|x_1-a_1|+|x_2-a_2|)$.

Comment: Hint: $cu + dv \le (c+ d)\max(u,v)$ for $c,d,u,v\ge0$.

Comment: However it is easier to show that $f(x) = x_i$ is continuous and then apply some multiplication and summation rules...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(x_n,y_n) \to (x_0,y_0)$ in the $d$-metric. Prove that then $x_n \to x_0, y_n \to y_0$ in the usual metric of $\mathbb R.$ From results you know, it then follows that $x_n^2 \to x_0^2, y_n^2 \to y_0^2,$ and hence $x_n^2 + y_n^2\to x_0^2+ y_0^2,$ again in the usual metric of $\mathbb R.$ Thus $(x_n,y_n) \to (x_0,y_0)$ in the $d$-metric implies $f(x_n, y_n) \to f(x_0,y_0)$ in the $\mathbb R$ metric. That is the desired conclusion.